# How can I set data in object using a string as the selector?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, set

Let's say I have a global object that's only accessible from one function which only accepts a string.

The following is defined inside a function.

```
function setItem(string, val) {

    var scope = [{
      apple : true, 
      test : 'aa'  
    },{
      apple : false,
      test : 'bb'
    }];
    var obj = {
        'deep' : scope
    }
    obj.string = val;
    return obj.string;
});
```

Now I want to get the first item, as well as overwrite data.

`setItem('scope[0].apple', 'apple is off'`);

Obviously the above isn't going to work when trying to set the variable, but I'm wondering if there's a way to evaluate the string value which can contain dotnotated and index selectors?

Comment: You could use `eval`.

Comment: @Barmar `eval('obj.scope[0].apple')` fails for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `eval`.

```js
function setItem(string, val) {
  var scope = [{
    apple: true,
    test: 'aa'
  }, {
    apple: false,
    test: 'bb'
  }];
  var obj = {
    'deep': scope
  }
  eval(string + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(val));
  return eval(string);
};
alert(setItem('scope[0].apple', 'apple is off'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this! And if I wanted to get the value rather than set it, how can I do that with eval?

Comment: `return eval(string);`